# How do I let moment know the date that I'm giving it is in UTC?

Tags: datetime, momentjs

Apologies in advance. Due to the popularity of this library I'm sure the answer is out there but I haven't been able to find it.

I'm getting timestamps back from an api in this format

```
2014-09-27T00:00:00-07:00
```

where this part is in UTC

```
2014-09-27T00:00:00
```

and this part is the timezone offset

```
-07:00
```

When converting to a moment I can't figure out how to let moment.js know that the time I'm passing it is in UTC.

If I try this

```
var time = moment('2014-09-27T00:00:00-07:00');
console.log(time.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
time.local();
console.log(time.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
```

both console logs output the same

however if I do this

```
var time = moment('2014-09-27T00:00:00-07:00');
time.utc();
console.log(time.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
time.local();
console.log(time.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
```

It will accurately add 7 hours (my time difference from UTC) log it, remove the time again and log it again.

I've tried

```
var time = moment.utc('2014-09-27T00:00:00-07:00');
```

but even then the .local() method doesn't do anything.

What am I missing?

An additional related question... In standard ISO 8601 format is the time string understood to be local time or UTC? With the offset one could convert in either direction, I'm just not sure what the starting point is.

Comment: Are you trying to parse it so that it will output 2014-09-27T00:00:00+00:00?  Because that timestamp is different than 2014-09-27T00:00:00-07:00.  If you want to parse 2014-09-27T00:00:00-07:00, then you should use parseZone() and then minus zone() minutes to get UTC value.  The easier way would be to remove the -07:00 part in the first place and parse with moment.utc()

Comment: In the course of troubleshooting this issue I've discovered I've been operating with a wrong assumption about how the iso8601 stamp is interpreted. I thought it was utcTime +- Offset and have since learned that it is LocalTime +- offset or utcTime + z (z is for zero offset). Now that I'm using the correct format, moment is working as expected.